# In iOS, can we set a UIButton's font and title and get its width?

Tags: ios, uibutton

In iOS, can we set a UIButton and get its width, or must be set its width and then set its content?

It seems that we can

```
[someString sizeWithFont:someFont].width
```

to get a width, and then make it the button's width (by setting its frame) and then set that title and font.  But can we just set a button's font and title (and autosize the button), and then get the width instead?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you suggested?

Comment: for example, a button might have the extra padding or border... so it will be good to be able to get a button's overall width

Comment: You can get the padding and border from the difference between button.titleLabel.frame and button.frame, and then resize with button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newWidth,1). Resizing like this will distort any features in your graphic tho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `sizeToFit` method of UIView (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW11)

```
[button setTitle:@"Hello World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button sizeToFit];
float width = button.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: seems to work well... set the content, and then send `sizeToFit` to the button, and then we can center the button using `aButton.center = ...` and access its `frame.size.width`

Comment: @Nosrettap, sizeToFit doesn't work for me. Width doesn't changes, but text was set to a bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

**sizeToFit** will work but it doesn't give you much flexibility as it wraps both the width and height around the text. A better method is to find out the size  which you can do with this...

**(iOS 8 and above)**

```
CGSize buttonSize = [button.titleLabel sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSFontAttributeName ,[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:9.0], nil]].width;
```

**(iOS 7 and below)**

```
CGSize buttonSize = [button.titleLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:9.0]].width;
```

Then you can add a margin etc by just adjusting the frame with the **buttonSize**

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize.width + 20, buttonSize.height)];
```